# Setting the MvxItemTeplate of an MvxListView inside a fragment

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

A fragment contains an MvxListView as in the simplified sample:

```
<!-- fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout>
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource TestItems"        
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/testitemtemplate"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result shows the list having items, but these are all empty.
When I remove the MvxItemTemplate, the items are being displayed with their ToString() values.

Do I forget something that needs to be done to have MvxListView inside a fragment to use the item template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the output log show any Mvx (probably bindings) errors?

Would be useful if you could show the code for the TestItems property and the axml for the testitemtemplate

Make sure the MvvmCross bindings in the testitemtemplate.axml are correctly declared.

Comment: also try adding a fixed height and background colour to the testitemtemplate - that might help show if the item template is being loaded.

Comment: Going over the trace output again I found the culprit of the problem. I had overlooked some code and looked at the wrong place (maybe 14 hours/day is too much..). Now it works as I wanted it to work ;-)